# Global Class/ variables not saving by setter

Tags: java, android, global-variables

I am attempting to use a global class to make the object data available through all of my activities. In my first activity, I am initializing my global class `patient`, and setting the variable with `setPatientName`. In my next activity, I call 'getPatientName', but it is returning `null`. When I try to set the result of 'getPatientName', it gives me the error

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference`

EDIT: My first activity is collecting the name from a text field, and that is what i'm trying to `setPatientName` as

The first activity:

```
 tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);

 EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    String nameString = name.getText().toString();

 final Patient p = (Patient) getApplicationContext();
    p.setPatientName(nameString);
```

The Second Activity:

```
Patient p = (Patient)getApplication();
String patName = p.getPatientName();
tv2.setText(patName);
```

The Patient class:

```
package com.example.imac.chs_pharmacy;

import android.app.Application;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.util.Log;

public class Patient extends Application {

    //private variables
    public String patient_name;

    //default constructor
    public Patient(){
    }

    public Patient(String startPatientName) {
        this.patient_name = startPatientName;
    }

    public void setPatientName( String patientName ){
        Log.d(TAG, "setting patient name");
        this.patient_name = patientName;
    }

    public String getPatientName( ){
        Log.d(TAG, "getting patient name");
        return this.patient_name;
}
```

manifest.xml:

```
<application android:name="com.example.imac.chs_pharmacy.Patient"
```

It's also worth noting that in my `Patient` class, i'm logging out a string in my `getPatientName` and `setPatientName`, but it only seems to be logging on the `setPatientName`. Is my `setPatientName` not getting fired off for some reason?

Comment: I think the problem is that your `tv2` variable is null.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to figure out why it's null

Comment: You should first check how you're retrieving the TextView, you haven't posted the code for that.

Comment: Ah I see. I didn't have the line `tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);` However, it's still not setting the name in the global variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need of extending `Application`. Try as below

```
public class Patient {

private static Patient patientInstance;

private String patient_name;

//private contrunctor to prevent from creating patient instance directly through constructor.
private Patient() {
}

public static Patient getInstance() {
  if (patientInstance == null) {
    patientInstance = new Patient();
  }
  return patientInstance;
}

public void setPatientName( String patientName ){
  this.patient_name = patientName;
}

public String getPatientName( ){
  return this.patient_name;
}
}
```

Then use the class as below

```
Patient p = Patient.getInstance();
String patName = p.getPatientName();
TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_text_view_id);
tv2.setText(patName);
```

Comment: Is it still going to be a global variable? I've never seen this format before, using `instance`

Comment: Does it still need to be declared in the AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Not needed to be declared in AndroidManifest.xml. Its just another java file.

Comment: I'm working on it. How do you start up an instance? I'm trying `Patient p = Patient.getInstance();
        p.setPatientName(nameString);` but it is saying string in patient cannot be applied to 0

Comment: I have updated the answer try it. changed the `public static Patient getInstance()` method in `Patient` class

Comment: Hm, it's still not getting to the setPatientName called from the first activity. It is however trying to retrieve it from getPatientName (from the second activity)

Comment: any suggestions? I've tried many things but the first activity will never set the patientName

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this solution:

public class Patient extends Application {

```
//private variables

public String patient_name = "StartPatientName"; 



 //default constructor    you should not ovveride Application class constructor!
 //    public Patient(){
 //    }

//  public Patient(String startPatientName) {
//    this.patient_name = startPatientName;
//}



public void setPatientName( String patientName ){
    Log.d(TAG, "setting patient name");
    this.patient_name = patientName;

}


public String getPatientName( ){
    Log.d(TAG, "getting patient name");
    return this.patient_name;
}
```

Also in the second activity init tv2 as below:

```
Patient p = (Patient)getApplication();
String patName = p.getPatientName();
TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_text_view_id);
tv2.setText(patName);
```

Comment: This code is working! However i'm stuck at the part where i'm defining "StartPatientName" please see edited question

Comment: why are you marking patient as final? This means you can't set a value for the patient name.

Comment: @FrankR I had just copied some code that I found. I took `final` off on both activities, but no change in result

Comment: Have you tried logging out the value being set in the setPatientName method? Maybe its an empty String or null.

Comment: This looks wrong: ` EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
` you are referring to the same TextView?

Comment: http://imgur.com/KUdrQ20 this is the view for the first activity. I am pulling from the first edit text